# Safety regarding multiple metals in same acid solution

Tags: home-experiment, safety

My son is testing the corrosion of metals in various solutions. Is it okay to place strips of multiple metals in the same container of a specific solution?

Metals being tested: $\ce{Fe}$, $\ce{Cu}$, $\ce{Zn}$, $\ce{Al}$

Solutions:

- Sulfuric acid (1 part acid, 8 parts water)
- Hydrochloric acid (1 part acid, 11 parts water)
- Copper Sulphate
- Hydrogen peroxide

Comment: Well, these things are mostly no more dangerous together than separately (which still means considerably dangerous). Anyway, I would do it in separate containers, so that the experiments wouldn't obscure the results of each other.

Comment: Ivan Neretin's comment is absolutely right! Use separate beakers to observe different reactivity, different colours, etc. Use gloves and, even more important, proper eye protection! And have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I agree with testing them separately, but still wanted to check if there were specific hazards or spoilers by combining certain metals. Looks like we will keep them separate for now.

Comment: I get nervous on a lot of inquiries like this. Proper chemical safety means being informed before some "accident" so that you know how to react. These chemicals are routinely handled and not particularly dangerous. You should use eye protection as noted. But you should also know how to flush eyes, that you'd need to strip and shower if you spill acid over a large part of your body (never take off clothes over the head - cut them off if need be...). Never work alone. Also how do you plan to dispose of the acids? So you need to plan for safety before using chemicals.